# How to fetch all Requests/Responses using Requests in Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I'm using selenium/ **Python** to automate one of my test scenarios, for which I need the **authentication token** to be passed.
To get this token, I need to read the headers of requests and find the request which has the token, using **requests**. 
To be more specific, after log in page and once the MSISDN (Phone number) is entered, multiple requests are sent and in one of these requests, in its header, **"Authentication" header** can be seen which has the value of SSO token I need.

What I want to do is to read all requests fired after MSISDN is entered ( about 30 requests) and find the one which has the authentication token in its header.

I've tried below:

```
from requests_toolbelt.utils import dump

response = requests.get(driver.current_url)
data = dump.dump_all(response)
print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

and the output is the response code and page source (html)

Trying **print(response.request.headers)** shows the first request which was fired.

Is there a way I can fetch all requests (their headers and payloads) and loop through the result to find a specific header using requests in Python?

I've attached a screen shot of request which are fired ( the one which has the authentication header is the last one in this case, but not always) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PezXJ.png)